# Issues with pointers when passing a struct to a thread on Win32 API

Tags: c, multithreading, winapi, pointers, struct

The user provides command line arguments that are used to compute the number of partitions, and the number of threads, where each thread does a minimum linear search of a specific partition of the large array. Each minimum value found by a thread is stored inside a small global array. The main function then does a minimum linear search of the small array, and also a minimum search of the large array and confirms that the minimum found in both small and large array are equal. The problem that I am encountering is that the minimums inside the small global array are sometimes garbage, and sometimes matches the minimum found in the large array. I have tried to figure out the problem but I don't seem to find it. Your help will be really appreciated. I am coding in C, using Dev-C++ on win32 API. The code is bellow:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <windows.h>

#define RAND_DIVISOR 800

int number_items = 0;
int size = 1;
int partits = 1;
int P = 0;
int N = 0;
int Index = 0;
int index_global = 0;
int min;


#define NUM_THREADS 65536  //or 2^16


typedef struct thread_data
{
int thread_id;
int a;
int b;
int * copy_array;
int * glob_array;
int nbr_items; 
int subarraysize;

} s_param, *p_s_param;


int compare (const void *a, const void *b)
{
return( *(int*)a - *(int*)b);

}


DWORD WINAPI CompMin( LPVOID lpParam )
{
    int i, tmp;
int SubArSize,nbrItems,thrid;
    p_s_param param2;
param2 = (p_s_param)lpParam;


min = param2->copy_array[Index];
min = param2->copy_array[param2->a];
param2->glob_array[index_global] = min; 
Index++;
index_global++;

    }


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{ 
    int sub_array_size;


p_s_param pDataArray[NUM_THREADS];
DWORD dwThreadIdArray[NUM_THREADS];
    HANDLE hThreadArray[NUM_THREADS]; 
HANDLE myhandle;
//pthread_t thID, thread;   

    p_s_param param[NUM_THREADS];
    int rNum, rc = 0, i, j, large_min;


    double time1, time2, time3, time4;

    //get initial timestamp in micro seconds
    struct timeval tv;
    gettimeofday( &tv, NULL );
    time1 = tv.tv_sec + ( tv.tv_usec / 1000000.0 );
    printf( "Start timestamp: %f\n", time1 );


    if(argc < 2 )
    {
        printf("Need %d arguments, only %d provided\n", 2, argc);
        printf("The program will exit now!\n");
        return 1;
    }

P = atoi(argv[1]); /* will be used to define size of large array */ 
N = atoi(argv[2]); /* will be used to define number of threads */ 

    if(N>P)
    {
    printf(" Argument 1 should be greater than argument 2\n");
        printf("The program will exit now!\n");
        return 1;
    }

/*compute the size of the array*/
for (i=1; i<=P; i++)
    size = size * 2;

/*Create a dynamic array of size size*/
int *array = (int*) malloc(size*sizeof(int));

srand(time(NULL));

for (i=0; i<size; i++) 
{
        rNum = rand() / RAND_DIVISOR;
    array[i] = rNum;

}

/*compute the number of partitions*/
for (i = 1; i<=N; i++)
    partits = partits * 2;

/*numbers of elements per sub array*/
sub_array_size = size/partits;

/*Global array*/
int *Globalarray = (int*) malloc(partits*sizeof(int));


    for (i=0; i<partits; i++)
    {

    /*Allocate memory for thread data*/
         param[i] = (p_s_param) HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, sizeof(s_param));

    if( param[i] == NULL)
    {
    ExitProcess(2);
    }

    param[i]->a=i;

    param[i]->copy_array=array;

    param[i]->glob_array = Globalarray;

hThreadArray[i] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, CompMin, param[i], 0, &dwThreadIdArray[i]);

    if(hThreadArray[i] == NULL)
    {
    puts("Error, cannot create Thread!");
    puts(strerror(errno));
    ExitProcess(3);

    }


    //printf("Number of partitions: %d\n",partits );    
}    WaitForMultipleObjects(NUM_THREADS,hThreadArray, TRUE, INFINITE);



    /*find mimimum value from Global array returned by threads*/
    min = Globalarray[0];
    for(i = 0; i< partits; i++)
    {   
        printf("Index: %d, value into small array: %d\n",i, Globalarray[i] );   
    if(Globalarray[i] < min)
        min = Globalarray[i];
    }


    gettimeofday( &tv, NULL );
    time2 = tv.tv_sec + ( tv.tv_usec / 1000000.0 );


    gettimeofday( &tv, NULL );
    time3 = tv.tv_sec + ( tv.tv_usec / 1000000.0 );

    /*sorting the large array in ascending order and find minimum value*/
    //qsort(array,size, sizeof(int), compare);
    large_min = array[0];
    for(i = 0; i< partits; i++)
    {
        printf("value into large array: %d\n",array[i] );   
    if(array[i] < large_min)
            large_min = array[i];
    }
    //large_min = array[0];

    gettimeofday( &tv, NULL );
    time4 = tv.tv_sec + ( tv.tv_usec / 1000000.0 );

    /*display result*/
    printf("Min from small array : %d\n", min);
    printf("Min from large array : %d\n", large_min);
    if(min == large_min)
    printf("Same minimum found in small and large array! : %d\n", large_min);

    else
    {   
        printf("error!, the min from small %d array is different from large array %d!\n", min, array[0]);

        return 1;
    }
    printf("length of time recorded to search min in small array: %f\n", time2-time1);

    printf("length of time recorded to search min in large array: %f\n", time4-time3);


    free((void*) Globalarray);
    free((void*) array); 


exit (0);

}
```

Comment: You probably need some sort of synchronisation on your global array. Also note that `WaitForMultipleObjects` can only wait on a maximum of 64 handles at a time, not 65536.

Comment: Well, this assignment states that we don't need synchronization since each thread will search the minimum on a specific partition.

Comment: `index_global` is a global variable shared by all threads, so how do you think they will avoid clashing?

Comment: I see what you mean. How can I avoid synchronization but forcing the main thread to wait for each thread to finish?  are you also saying that after 64 handles clash will likely happen? Is there any way to set the wait up to 65536?

Comment: My attempt of solution was to replace index_global by the thread ID of each individual thread. But it did not fix the problem.

Comment: Creating 65536 threads will thrash the system and accomplish nothing. For one thing, it will require 64GB of memory just for stacks. For another, all the context switches will kill your throughput. Just create one thread per core.

Answer (score 1):

I just added a sleep(3) after the wait, and it fixed the problem.

Comment: ... then your certainly have a race condition.

Comment: Never use Sleep(3), it may crash anytime. Use Sleep(42)

Answer (score 0):

Your `CompMin()` function is not thread-safe.  It is accessing global variables that are shared and modified by multiple threads at the same time, so they are going to step over each other's data as they run in parallel to each other.  You need to make your work data self-contained so each thread is only operating on the data it is given to work on, and get rid of your shared globals altogether.  You designed your `thread_data` struct to allow partitioning the array data, but you are not actually utilizing that functionality, so each thread is not searching its individual partition of data, and not storing its search result in its individual section of the global array.

You are also passing the wrong number of thread handles to `WaitForMultipleObjects()`, so it will fail to wait, which you are not checking for, and then you move on to process the array data before they are actually ready to be processed.

Your are also searching the arrays incorrectly after the threads have finished running, so you are not going to end up with the correct results.

Try something more like this instead:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <windows.h>

#define RAND_DIVISOR 800

typedef struct thread_data
{
    DWORD thread_id;
    int *items;
    int nbr_items; 
    int min;

} s_thread_data, *p_s_thread_data;

/*
int compare (const void *a, const void *b)
{
    return( *(int*)a - *(int*)b);
}
*/

DWORD WINAPI CompMin( LPVOID lpParam )
{
    p_s_thread_data data = (p_s_thread_data) lpParam;
    int i;

    data->min = data->items[0];
    for(i = 1; i < data->nbr_items; i++)
    {   
        if(data->items[i] < data->min)
            data->min = data->items[i];
    }

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{ 
    int size = 1;
    int partits = 1;
    int sub_array_size;
    int i;

    if(argc < 2 )
    {
        printf("Need %d arguments, only %d provided\n", 2, argc);
        printf("The program will exit now!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int P = atoi(argv[1]); /* will be used to define size of large array */ 
    if(P < 1)
    {
        printf(" Argument 1 should be greater than zero\n");
        printf("The program will exit now!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int N = atoi(argv[2]); /* will be used to define number of threads */ 
    if(N < 1)
    {
        printf(" Argument 2 should be greater than zero\n");
        printf("The program will exit now!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    /*compute the size of the large array*/
    for (i=1; i<=P; i++)
        size = size * 2;

    /*Allocate memory for large array*/
    int *array = (int*) malloc(size*sizeof(int));
    if(array == NULL)
        return 2;

    srand(time(NULL));

    /*Fill the large array with random data*/
    for (i=0; i<size; i++) 
        array[i] = rand() / RAND_DIVISOR;

    /*compute the number of partitions*/
    for (i = 1; i<=N; i++)
        partits = partits * 2;

    //printf("Number of partitions: %d\n", partits );    

    /*numbers of elements per partition*/
    sub_array_size = size/partits;

    /*Allocate memory for thread data*/
    p_s_thread_data ThreadDataArray = (p_s_thread_data) malloc(partits*sizeof(s_thread_data));
    if(ThreadDataArray == NULL)
        return 2;
    memset(ThreadDataArray, 0, partits*sizeof(s_thread_data));

    /*Allocate memory for thread handles array*/
    HANDLE *hThreadArray = (HANDLE*) malloc(partits*sizeof(HANDLE)); 
    if(hThreadArray == NULL)
        return 2;
    memset(hThreadArray, 0, partits*sizeof(HANDLE));

    double time1, time2, time3, time4;

    //get initial timestamp in micro seconds
    struct timeval tv;
    gettimeofday( &tv, NULL );
    time1 = tv.tv_sec + ( tv.tv_usec / 1000000.0 );
    printf( "Start timestamp: %f\n", time1 );

    for (i=0; i<partits; i++)
    {
        ThreadDataArray[i].items = &array[i*sub_array_size];
        ThreadDataArray[1].nbr_items = sub_array_size; 

        hThreadArray[i] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, CompMin, &param[i], 0, &(param[i].thread_id));

        if(hThreadArray[i] == NULL)
        {
            printf("Error, cannot create Thread! %s\n", strerror(errno));
            return 3;
        }
    }

    /*Wait for threads to finish*/
    i = 0;
    int nbr_handles = partits;
    while (nbr_handles >= MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS)
    {
        if (WaitForMultipleObjects(MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS, &hThreadArray[i], TRUE, INFINITE) != WAIT_OBJECT_0)
            return 4;

        i = i + MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS;
        nbr_handles = nbr_handles - MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS;
    }
    if (nbr_handles > 0)
    {
        if (WaitForMultipleObjects(nbr_handles, &hThreadArray[i], TRUE, INFINITE) != WAIT_OBJECT_0)
            return 4;
    }

    /*find minimum value from thread results*/
    int min = ThreadDataArray[0].min;
    for(i = 0; i < partits; i++)
    {   
        printf("Index: %d, value into small array: %d\n",i, ThreadDataArray[i].min );   
        if(ThreadDataArray[i].min < min)
            min = ThreadDataArray[i].min;
    }

    gettimeofday( &tv, NULL );
    time2 = tv.tv_sec + ( tv.tv_usec / 1000000.0 );

    gettimeofday( &tv, NULL );
    time3 = tv.tv_sec + ( tv.tv_usec / 1000000.0 );

    /*sorting the large array in ascending order and find minimum value*/
    //qsort(array,size, sizeof(int), compare);
    int large_min = array[0];
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("value into large array: %d\n", array[i] );   
        if(array[i] < large_min)
            large_min = array[i];
    }

    gettimeofday( &tv, NULL );
    time4 = tv.tv_sec + ( tv.tv_usec / 1000000.0 );

    /*display result*/
    printf("Min from small array : %d\n", min);
    printf("Min from large array : %d\n", large_min);
    if(min == large_min)
        printf("Same minimum found in small and large array! : %d\n", large_min);
    else
    {   
        printf("error!, the min from small array (%d) is different from large array (%d)!\n", min, large_min);
        return 1;
    }

    printf("length of time recorded to search min in small array: %f\n", time2-time1);
    printf("length of time recorded to search min in large array: %f\n", time4-time3);

    free(array); 
    free(ThreadDataArray);
    free(hThreadArray);

    return 0;
}
```